# When is there a U instead of an E in gerund(ive)?

Tags: morphology, gerund, gerundive, vowel

Tuomo Pekkanen's Latin grammar mentions (§52.3) that the *-e-* added to the present stem before *-nd-* in the gerund and gerundive (in the third and fourth conjugations) can be replaced with a *-u-*.
For example, *mittendus = mittundus* and *faciendus = faciundus*.
No more details are given.

When can I one replace the typical *-e-* with *-u-*?
Is this specific to some era, author, or verbs?
Would it be appropriate to occasionally make the replacement in any context?

I wanted to understand the *-e-*/*-u-* variations in gerund(ive)s better.
The variations can also be across words, not only within single words; I consider both variations to be essentially the same phenomenon.

Comment: It's the older form. Consider also the old present passive participle *alumnus* (from *alo, alere*), which would've probably been *alemnus* had it been formed in Classical Latin.

Comment: @Anonym Somehow I suspected that might be the case, but I had no evidence for it. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/present-stem a page from Allen and Greenough that mentions that e/i/u in this kind of context generally comes from a Proto-Indo-European "thematic vowel" which apparently had ablaut variants \*e (> Latin *e, i*) and \*o (> Latin *u*)

Comment: Gerends? Gerendives?

Comment: @Draconis I'm sure such forms would make many furibend if not moribend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weiss writes that

> "**The *u*-forms are characteristic of legal and archaizing style**, e.g. *pecuniae repetundae* (the recovery of extorted money), and are found in the isolated forms *secundus* 'following' and *rotundus* 'round' (p. 444; emphasis mine - Alex B.).

[Powell 2007/2011](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781444343397.ch26/summary) adds that even though "the gerundive suffix in -*undus*, rather than -*endus*, has an old-fashioned flavor and is characteristic of legal Latin," **"neither confined to it nor universal in it"** (p. 482, note 21; emphasis mine - Alex B.).

As for specific authors, Leumann 1977 (p. 331) mentions first Plautus and Terence (Neue and Wagener write that the u-forms are *gewöhnliche*, i.e. usual/normal, in Plautus and Terence, p. 332); also Sallust and Gellius, cf.:

> c) Für *-endo-* erscheint bei Verben der 3. und 4. Konjug. archaisierend oft *-undo-* (aus *-ondo-*), so meist Plt. Ter., dann Sall. Gell., auch inschr. Lex repett. (ausgenommen 65 *tribuendei,* also hinter *u*), D 620 *veniundum est*; archaisch wohl *emundi* und *vendundi* bei Cic.; alte Formel dat. *iure dicundo*; immer *eundo-* (wie ptc. *eunt-*) zu *īre.* Nur hinter *u u̯ qu̯* scheint *-undo-* früh gemieden worden zu sein (doch beachte oben *secundus*): *loquendi* Plt., *volvendus* Enn., *restituendos* D 460, oben *tribuendei.* Danach ist vermutlich ursprüngliches *-ondo-* an ptc. *-ent-* zu *-endo-* angeglichen worden; bei dieser Annahme kann das *-end-* nicht auf idg. *-n̥d-* zurückgehen.

From the above quote from Leumann, we can also learn that in verbs whose stem ended in **u, u̯, qu** the *u*-forms were avoided in Latin - the only exception to this observation seems to be *secundus*.

For more examples, see pp. 331-340 in [Neue and Wagener 1897, volume 3: Das Verbum](https://archive.org/details/formenlehrederla03neueuoft)

Comment: @hexadecimal Let me try to clarify the point Alex B. and sumelic are making. The stem in *oriundus* is *ori-*, and it ends in *i*. However, if the stem ends in *u*, *u̯*, or *qu*, then *-undus* is not possible; *-endus* is the only option. The only exception to this rule is *secundus* (< *sequundus*?). Here the stem ends in *qu*. The rule only concerns verbs with stem ending in *u*, *u̯*, or *qu*, so *oriri* (like most other verbs) is not covered by this rule. For example, this rule prohibits *loquundum* but not *trahundum*. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 4):

To clarify a little more.

In Gramatica Latina (latin grammar) by Santiago Segura:

**Participe of passive future**:
It is also called verbal adjective in -NDUS and gerundive and is formed by adding to the present theme the suffix -ND-US, -ND-A, -ND-UM, sometimes by -e- (3rd and 4th conjugation): ama- ndus, -a, -um; dele-nd-us, -a, -um; leg-e-nd-us, -a, -um; cap-i-e-nd-dus, -a, -um; audi-e-nd-us, -a, -um. It is declined as a bonus, -a, -um.

In the archaic period the verbs of the 3rd and 4th conjugation offer forms in -undus (with vocalism o> u, instead of e): legundis, deferundo, querundai, repetunda. The analogical action of the present participle in -e-ns, -e-ntis made generalize the form in -endus, surviving scarce forms in -undus in the **archaizing language of the law** (repetundis) **or as adjectives** (oriundus, secundus and others).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to Alex B's answer, though I can't offer as authoritative of sources:

> Would it be appropriate to occasionally make the replacement in any context?

In the late Republican period, the answer seems to be **yes, but it sounds a bit archaic**. I'd compare it to putting the object before the verb in English ("speaking with the object the verb preceding"): people will understand it readily, and it's perfectly acceptable for poetic purposes, but it's not how people actually speak in day to day life.

Historically, based on corpus searches:

- Plautus and Terence tend to prefer *-und-* over *-end-*, though they use both
- Cato tends to prefer *-end-* over *-und-*, though he uses both
- Both Sallust and Lucretius chose to use *-und-* almost universally as a stylistic choice, and were both considered deliberately archaicizing—but not difficult to understand
- Caesar uses *-und-* very rarely, heavily preferring *-end-*
- Cicero uses *-end-* (almost?) exclusively
- Vergil never uses *-und-* as far as I can tell, except in fossilized *secundum*

So in the famous authors at least, it's clear that *-und-* was steadily dying out in the second century BCE, and was considered somewhat archaic during the first.

After that, during Imperial times, it was presumably still understood, but I haven't been able to find it used with any sort of frequency. I assume it was treated more like the verb endings *-est* and *-eth* in English: people will still unambiguously understand "whither goest thou?", but even in poetry it's considered extremely archaic, and is a stylistic affectation more than anything else.