# Why does "abesse" have a present active participle while "adesse" does not?

Tags: verbs, conjugation

I found that the verb **"Abesse"** unlike **"Esse"** or **"Adesse"** has a present active participle.
What makes "Abesse" different?

Comment: Isn't the present active participle of "esse" "essens"?

Comment: @FlatAssembler Absolutely not. The expected participle is *sōns* (still preserved as an adjective with a different meaning), and *ēns* was coined in the classical period but never widely used.

Comment: You also have *praesens*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frequency of use, really!

Originally, *esse* had a perfectly regular present participle—or at least as regular as a verb like *esse* can be. This was *sōns*, *sontis*, inherited from PIE **h₁sonts*.

However, Latin didn't really need a word for "being" as much as English does. English uses "being" to form passive participles, for example, but Latin doesn't; to express "the ones who are being seen" you can use an adjective, a perfect form, or a relative clause.

As a result, *sōns* wasn't used very much, and became a specialized technical term in law. Eventually it no longer meant "being" at all. Eventually, [under the influences of Greek and Romance, new present participles were invented](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/12560/406): **essēns* and *ēns*. But in Classical Latin, there simply isn't a participle "being", and people did fine without one. Even in later forms of the language, *ēns* has never been anywhere near as widespread as English "being".

But, some prefixed forms of *esse* **did** use their participles all the time! "The ones who are here" and "the ones who aren't here" are very useful, for example, so *praesēns* and *absēns* (from *sōns* via vowel reduction) were quite popular, and thus didn't disappear from everyday use the way *sōns* itself did.

The result was a perception that *esse* didn't have a present participle, and thus none of its derived forms (*adesse*, *deesse*) did either…except the ones where that participle was useful enough that it remained popular in everyday use, *absēns* and *praesēns*.

Comment: Very thought-provoking statements about language evolution here (or should we say devolution); Do words disappear because they are "not needed"? maybe there is chicken-egg issue involved here. I say that if *sons* was used, then a "need" would have been "found" to "justify" its existence. (I know how odd this sounds, but the point is there are many words in every language that are "not needed" yet still with us). Other than that, one can see a usage for this participle is AA constructions that is simply being omitted; e.g. "caesare duce" .

Comment: @d_e Well, if a word _does_ get used, presumably its users found it useful! Since we can say from the surviving corpus that people _didn't_ use sōns to mean "being" very often, it doesn't seem like much of a stretch to say they weren't finding it very useful for that purpose.

Comment: right. The crux question then moves to "usage". For some reason *sons* was not used -- but is it because it was not useful? If we look at many of distinct words in English - there are clearly useful - I once encountered the dying word *malapert* in some old text (I think one Loeb translation :) ) and found that word useful and handy. then finding out it was marked as *archaic* by Wiktionary (and indeed many native speakers are not familiar with that word) - one step before "obsolete." why is that?

Comment: @d_e If nobody will understand you when you say it, is it really useful?

Comment: I see [Wiktionary gives the same explanation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sons#Latin), but I don't think vowel reduction would actually result in sons/sont- changing to sens/sent- in a non-initial syllable. The usual reduction outcome of -o- in a closed medial or final syllable is -u-, as in the third-declension present 3rd person plural endings -unt, -untur or the [old gerundive ending -undus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4807). Sont- vs. -sent- look more like ablaut variants (I don't know the reason for that, but it could be as simple as analogy with other participles).

Comment: If a world celeb, or be it Cicero, start using the word *malapert* would  not the word be used then?  I say that in the ecosystem of a living language there are several factors determining the fate of a word. I venture to baseless guess that chaotic factors are there. Surely *malapert* was and still is an *intrinsically* useful word - it was just replaced by other almost synonym word(s).  The diminishing *intrinsic* value of words does count but only a small factor in language evolution: such as some specific agriculture words that surely now gone. All I offer is a point for thought.

Comment: That was insightful, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question so much as replacing it with a different question: if the pres. ppl. of "be" really was so infrequent in Latin that it was lost, why was that? The corresponding form in Greek is very frequent, and it's not clear to me what syntactic differences between the two languages would account for the discrepancy.

Comment: @TKR If I had to guess, I'd say Greek loves its participles much more than Latin does, with a much more thorough complement of them; as a result, participles for "function" verbs end up getting more use than in Latin.

Answer (score -2):

It's perhaps a bit confusing, to compare English 'to be ' to Latin 'esse'. It's more clearly to interpret in Greek  and  high German  languages where a participial construction like "I am being" translates to "I exist" and in low German dialects to "Ich bin am seien". The so called "Rheinische Verlaufsform" constuctions  are still popular in the Ruhr area dialects.

The Romans and the Humanists after Luther discarded such philosophical terms of existentialism as pure linguistic jokes, mainly used by the  Greek philosphers as house slaves to make their Latin speaking patrons feel humbled intellectually.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: Difficult, similarly difficult as explaining how such a question is arising for Latin, a Language incapable to cope with philosophy at the classical level. Confer Shakespeare, Descartes or Heidegger for the reivival of all the ancient questions of "To be".