# Why sōns but absēns?

Tags: etymology, participle, vowel

The present participle of *esse* was (at one point) *sōns*, presumably from **h₁sonts*. However, when a prefix is attached, it becomes *-sēns*, as in *absēns* and *praesēns*.

I'd always figured this was a relic of vowel reduction in non-initial syllables, like why we see *facere* but *interficere*. But [Asteroides disagrees](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/why-does-abesse-have-a-present-active-participle-while-adesse-does-not#comment44428_21395):

> I don't think vowel reduction would actually result in sons/sont- changing to sens/sent- in a non-initial syllable. The usual reduction outcome of -o- in a closed medial or final syllable is -u-, as in the third-declension present 3rd person plural endings -unt, -untur or the old gerundive ending -undus. Sont- vs. -sent- look more like ablaut variants (I don't know the reason for that, but it could be as simple as analogy with other participles).

So: why *do* we see *sōns* next to *-sēns*? Is this how vowel reduction works before *-ns* (which we know lengthens vowels, and I can't think of any other instances of vowel reduction before it)? Or does ablaut or analogy factor in somehow?

Answer (score 9):

Ruppel 2013 seems to offer the kind of explanation that I was thinking of, that *absens* and *praesens* were simply adapted to make their endings fit better with the usual morphology of Latin third-conjugation present participles:

> The form we do find, *sons,* is used to mean 'guilty' ('he who (really) was it, he who is the real author of the thing in question'). In *absens* and *praesens*, the root vowel has been adapted to fit the vocalism of other regular present active participles. This is why I am referring to asterisked **sens* in this section.

([page 121](https://books.google.com/books?id=-VogAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121), *Absolute Constructions in Early Indo-European,* Antonia Ruppel, 2013)

A relevant question is obviously how other regular present active participles developed their vocalism, and what the vocalism was in Proto-Indo-European. Sihler 1995 says the following:

> 556. STEM ABLAUT. The full grade of the suffix **-ont-* alternated with the zero grade **-n̥t-* in the usual hysterokinetic way (full grade in nom./acc., zero grade in most other cases, **272.3, 273**); the nom.sg. presents a special problem, about which more below (**558**). The ablaut of the suffix was the same for thematic and athematic types, that is, a complex like **bheront-* 'carrying' is to be segmented **bher-ont-,*<sup>1</sup> in contradistinction to the segmentation of the similar-looking thematic 3pl. **bher-o-nti*. This indicates once upon a time the affix was in fact originally added to roots rather than stems, just like the verbal nouns. [...]

> 559. I. In ITALIC, uniquely, it was the zero grade of the stem that was generalized in the participles [...] and the resulting stems *ferent-, legent-* ousted all *o*-grade forms apart from the isolated *sons,* and *eunt-* (below). [...] Traces of the original *o*-grade can be found in *voluntāt-* 'will, wish', which enshrines **welont-*; cf. *volēns.*

(pp. 613-616, *New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin,* Andrew L. Sihler)

If I'm reading the next quote correctly, it seems Jacob Wackernagel disputed that *sons* actually represents the participle of *esse*:

> Not even the present participle in *-ns* is completely preserved in Latin. By no means every verb has it. Especially striking is the loss of **sens* 'being'. Apart from the old sacral expression *Di consentes* (connected by the ancients with *consentire* ('agree with'), but rightly interpreted already generations ago by J. M. Gesner (1749) as meaning 'being with'), the participle of 'to be' survives only in *absens* and *praesens* (and in the latter with a shift of meaning). [...] The old suggestion that *sons* 'guilty' is the equivalent of Greek *ὤν* and means 'the one who is it' does not deserve to be pursued.

([pages 356-357](https://books.google.com/books?id=dSISDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA356), *Participles* in "Jacob Wackernagel, Lectures on Syntax: With Special Reference to Greek, Latin and Germanic", edited by David Langslow, 2009)

#### Vowel reduction

As for vowel reduction before *-ns-,* there appears to be an example in *-scēns-,* the supine stem for compounds of *scando* (*ascendo, dēscendō, escendo*). This could conceivably be an analogical formation from the vowel in the present stem *-scend-*, but we know from verbs like *impingo, impāctum* that analogy did not inevitably result in leveling of quality differences created by vowel reduction between the present and supine stems of verbs, so *-scēns-* seems to provide some support for ordering the rule of non-initial-syllable vowel reduction before the rule of pre-NS lengthening. Weiss 2009 cites the example of *ascendere* and gives an etymology for *anhēlō* that also requires this rule ordering: "**an-an-slō* 'I pant' > **an-enslō* > *an(h)ēlō*" (page 177, *Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*, Michael Weiss).

But both of these examples show the outcome of the vowel *-a-,* which regularly yields *-e-* when reduced in closed syllables. As I mentioned, *-o-* in closed syllables regularly yields *-u-* when reduced. Although I know of no certain examples of this outcome where the *-o-* precedes /ns/, it hardly seems simpler to suppose a special phonetic development in this case than to explain the *-ens* in the nominative singular of *absens, praesens* and other third-conjugation participles by means of analogy, which seems to have caused leveling of many inflectional paradigms that originally featured ablaut (compare *pēs* vs. Greek *πούς* and English *foot*).